# How to desgin class structure while using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: asp.net, json

I want to import some data from a json file to a class, it's very clear in PHP but in ASP.net I really don't know how to desgin the class structure while I trying to use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() to deserialize the json string.
Here is my json string:

```
{
    "video": {
        "path": {
            "source": "d:/videos/",
            "temp": "d:/temp/",
            "dest": "d:/dest/videos/"
        },
        "allowExt": ["avi", "mp4"],
        "bitrate": "1600"
    },
    "photo": {
        "path": {
            "source": "d:/photos/",
            "temp": "d:/temp/",
            "dest": "d:/dest/photoss/"
        },
        "allowExt": ["jpg", "png"],
        "quality": "80"
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try creating a class? Adding appropriate properties for the top level properties? Create classes to represent the complex objects under that? Did you try searching the web for a tool that can generate classes for you from JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of online tools for creating models and mappings from json to (almost any language)

The one that suits your needs: https://json2csharp.com/

(Just copy-paste your json to left textarea, click "Convert", be happy)

Another good one is: https://app.quicktype.io/ but it uses Newtonsoft.Json